# Using the cell value as the cell range for calculation

Tags: excel, excel-2010, date-range, standard-deviation, vba

I am new to VBA. I am presently working on a validation tool already built by my predecessor. 
The issue I want clarification on is selecting the cell range based on the result of a formula in another cell.

For example,
I need to find the standard deviation of 800 number among the 1000 numbers of a column say Column B.
I use the formula STDEV.S(), with the range of two cells in the bracket. However, the range of two cells is varying, as the user can select and change the range. The selection of the range by user is printed in a cell, say Upper Limit in C16 and lower Limit in  C15. Consider C16 has 950 and C16 has 150 value in them, in that case, how do I insert the formula for stdev.s().?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Data is in Column B and your bounds are in C15 and C16

```
Sub PasteAFormula()

Dim strFormulaToPaste As String

    strFormulaToPaste = "B" & Range("C15").Value & ":B" & Range("C16").Value

    strFormulaToPaste = "=STDEV.S(" & strFormulaToPaste & ")"

    MsgBox strFormulaToPaste

End Sub
```

You can then put the contents of strFormulaToPaste into a cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.. Works like a charm.. :) This is what I have been looking for. :) :)

Comment: Glad it works. Could you tick the answer as correct to ensure that it can be picked up if anyone else asks a similar question? Thanks.